# Video not showing (00:00 length), example works, links ok

Tags: mediaelement.js

spent hours trying to implement mediaelement.js (v.2.1.2) in wordpress v.3.1.2 running on an apache with corectly configured MIME types...

The example first (plays nice) and then my own vid (no length, no poster, just black)

the page is:
http://ronhardt.org/site/?page_id=79

Here are two lines in my page

> [video
>   mp4="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"
>   ogg="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogg"
>   webm="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm"
>   poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
>   preload="true" autoplay="true"
>   width="640" height="264"]

---

> [video
>   mp4="http://ronhardt.org/site/wp-content/uploads/vid/webface002.mp4"
>   ogg="http://ronhardt.org/site/wp-content/uploads/vid/webface002.ogg"
>   webm="http://ronhardt.org/site/wp-content/uploads/vid/webface002.webm"
>   poster="http://ronhardt.org/site/wp-content/uploads/vid/webface001.png"
>   preload="true" autoplay="true"
>   width="250" height="250"]

Any help would be greatly appeciated ; )

Kind regards, Ubbo

Answer (score 0):

You're using the video.js short code. Video.js isn't the same as mediaelement.js.